# How to hide the scrollbar in DXGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, devexpress, scrollbar

How can I hide the scrollbar in DevExpress DXGrid (WPF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this task, use the [TableView.HorizontalScrollbarVisibility](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableView_HorizontalScrollbarVisibilitytopic)/[TableView.VerticalScrollbarVisibility](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableView_VerticalScrollbarVisibilitytopic) properties.